# Calling overloaded super constructor in ScalaJS class that extends a native class

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I have this JavaScript class/constructor:

```
function Grid(size, tileFactory, previousState, over, won) {
    this.size        = size;
    this.tileFactory = tileFactory;
    this.cells       = previousState ? this.fromState(previousState) : this.empty();
    this.over        = over ? over : false;
    this.won         = won ? won : false;
}
```

Which I have mapped using this ScalaJS facade:

```
@js.native
class Grid[T <: Tile](val size: Int,
                      val tileFactory: TileFactory[T],
                      previousState: js.Array[js.Array[TileSerialized]],
                      val over: Boolean,
                      val won: Boolean) extends js.Object {

  val cells: js.Array[js.Array[T]] = js.native

  def this(size: Int, tileFactory: TileFactory[T]) = this(???, ???, ???, ???, ???)

  ...

}
```

I want to extend the `Grid` class, which I have done like so:

```
@ScalaJSDefined
class ExtendedGrid(
                    override val size: Int,
                    override val tileFactory: TileFactory[Tile],
                    previousState: js.Array[js.Array[TileSerialized]],
                    override val over: Boolean,
                    override val won: Boolean) extends Grid(size, tileFactory, previousState, over, won) {

  ...

}
```

But now I also need to implement the overloaded constructor for this `ExtendedGrid` class.

*Problem* is, **how do I do that?**

---

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
def this(size: Int, tileFactory: TileFactory[Tile]) = super(size: Int, tileFactory: TileFactory[Tile])
```

but from what I understand, that is not possible in Scala.

Just to try it out, I tried to just plainly copy the original overloaded constructor I had defined in my facade:

```
def this(size: Int, tileFactory: TileFactory[T]) = this(???, ???, ???, ???, ???)
```

which did compile but *obviously* resulted in a browser error:

```
Uncaught scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

I then tried:

```
def this(size: Int, tileFactory: TileFactory[Tile]) = this(size, tileFactory, this.empty(), false, false)
```

to mimic the behavior of the original JavaScript function but to no avail. It produces this error:

```
this can be used only in a class, object, or template
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you're trying to call is not *really* overloaded. It is closer to having *default parameters* with optional values. In JS, default parameters are basically `undefined`. So you can model the parent constructor differently:

```
@js.native
class Grid[T <: Tile](val size: Int,
                      val tileFactory: TileFactory[T],
                      previousState: js.UndefOr[js.Array[js.Array[TileSerialized]]] = js.undefined,
                      _over: js.UndefOr[Boolean] = js.undefined,
                      _won: js.UndefOr[Boolean] = js.undefined) extends js.Object {
  val over: Boolean = js.native
  val won: Boolean = js.native
  val cells: js.Array[js.Array[T]] = js.native

  ...
}
```

Then you can mimic the same structure when defining your class:

```
@ScalaJSDefined
class ExtendedGrid(size: Int,
                   tileFactory: TileFactory[Tile],
                   previousState: js.UndefOr[js.Array[js.Array[TileSerialized]]] = js.undefined,
                   _over: js.UndefOr[Boolean] = js.undefined,
                   _won: js.UndefOr[Boolean] = js.undefined) extends Grid(size, tileFactory, previousState, _over, _won) {

  ...

}
```

Btw, do not use `override val`, since you're passing the value to the parent constructor, and you get the `val` from your superclass.